# Any way to close Casperjs from a listener?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I want casperjs to `exit()` every time a certain event listener is triggered:

```
casper.on "error", (e, stack) ->
    console.log(JSON.stringify({'error': e, 'stack': stack}))
    store_error(request_id, 'internal_error', {})
    # casper.exit()
    # @exit()
```

However, neither of these attempts work. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
casper.then ->
    @exit()
```